# How to find distribution?

Tags: classification, normal-distribution

Following information is available about the binomial distribution of a discrete variable X Mean of the binomial distribution equal 16/3 and variance equal 16/9 find the distribution?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

You may ask yourself the following:

- On what does the mean of a binomial distribution depend?
- On what does the variance of a binomial distribution depend?

Answering these two questions will yield the a system of unknowns, which, given the information in your question, will allow you to answer it.